# Itsdangerous security - TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'bytes'

Tags: python, itsdangerous

I am using Python 3.9 and itsdangerous 2.1.2. I was testing things in the terminal and it does not appear to be working. This is my first experience with itsdangerous so maybe I don't understand it.

I want to get a token that can be emailed for when the user clicks on [forgot password].

My code in terminal:

```
>>> from itsdangerous import URLSafeTimedSerializer as Serializer
>>> s = Serializer('secret', 300)
>>> token = s.dumps({'user_id': 5}).decode('utf-8')
```

From above I get an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\...\flask_env\lib\site-packages\itsdangerous\serializer.py", line 208, in dumps
    rv = self.make_signer(salt).sign(payload)
  File "C:\...\flask_env\lib\site-packages\itsdangerous\timed.py", line 55, in sign
    return value + sep + self.get_signature(value)
  File "C:\...\flask_env\lib\site-packages\itsdangerous\signer.py", line 209, in get_signature
    key = self.derive_key()
  File "C:\...\flask_env\lib\site-packages\itsdangerous\signer.py", line 195, in derive_key
    bytes, self.digest_method(self.salt + b"signer" + secret_key).digest()
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'bytes'
```

After seeing [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75197102/5091720) I changed to the below.

```
>>> from itsdangerous import URLSafeTimedSerializer as Serializer
>>> s = Serializer('secret')
>>> token = s.dumps({'user_id': 5})
>>> s.loads(token)
{'user_id': 5}
>>> token          
'eyJ1c2VyX2lkIjo1fQ.ZEv06A.rc99R7V53CJ1XDM0sk6VJjMFdjQ'
```

Part of the concept of the integer in `s = Serializer('secret', 300)` is to limit the time for the token to work. If I change to the 2nd option will the `Serializer` go to a default time out? How could I make it work better?

Is there any concern with having this be the code of a token for a flask app? If it does seem wrong how should I do it?

```
def get_reset_token(self):
    s = Serializer(app.config['SECRET_KEY'])
    return s.dumps({'user_id': self.id})
```

Comment: Don't remove part of the traceback. That is the most useful information to debug.

Comment: @SimonUnderwood - I added the full traceback

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [docs](https://itsdangerous.palletsprojects.com/en/2.1.x/url_safe/), 2nd argument to `URLSafeTimedSerializer` is `salt` which has default value `b'itsdangerous'` and if given it should be `str` or `bytes` instance, `300` is literal for integer and therefore does not met imposed requirments.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Would you adjust the code to make it more secure? See my edit at the bottom of the question.

Comment: @ShaneS That sounds like it could be a new question.

Answer (score 2):

You should pass `max_age` on `loads()` to limit the time for your token

```
>>> from itsdangerous import URLSafeTimedSerializer as Serializer
>>> s =Serializer('secret')
>>> token = s.dumps({'user_id': 5})
>>> s.loads(token, max_age=60)
 {'user_id': 5}
>>> s.loads(token, max_age=60)
```

If you call it after 60s, you get `SignatureExpired` exception.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>   
File "C:\dev\project_flask\FARPiscine_project\FARPiscine-deploy-db- 
V1\.venv\lib\site-packages\itsdangerous\timed.py",line 210, in loads
     base64d, timestamp = signer.unsign(   
File "C:\dev\project_flask\FARPiscine_project\FARPiscine-deploy-db- 
 V1\.venv\lib\site-packages\itsdangerous\timed.py", line 148, in unsign
     raise SignatureExpired( 
itsdangerous.exc.SignatureExpired: Signature age 64 > 60 seconds
```